# Detect marker snippet open and close

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I need to be able to detect when the marker snippet is open and when it closes.

To detect when snippet open I can use:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
       //My code here

       return true;
  }
});
```

How I can detect when marker snippet close?

Comment: Use setTag() , getTag() to set open, close in Marker.

Comment: I do not understand what you say.

Comment: use marker.setTag() method to set snippet as open when you clicked on it first time and when you clicked again check you tag by using marker.getTag() method and if got open then Assume it as close.